# Jvectormap hovering displays the province name twice

Tags: angular, angular6, jvectormap, jqvmap

So I am implementing a jvectormap of The Netherlands and now I get a double nametag of the province when I hover the map.

[image]

**IN HTML**

```
 <div id="worldMap" style="height: 385px;"></div>
```

**IN COMPONENT**

```
var mapData = {
        "NL-ZH": 100000
    };
    $('#worldMap').vectorMap({
        map: 'nl_mill',
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        zoomOnScroll: false,
        regionStyle: {
            initial: {
                fill: '#e4e4e4',
                "fill-opacity": 0.9,
                stroke: 'none',
                "stroke-width": 0,
                "stroke-opacity": 0
            }
        },

        series: {
            regions: [{
                values: mapData,
                scale: ["#AAAAAA","#444444"],
                normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
            }]
        },
    });
```

As you can see below twice a *jvectormap-tip* is generated.

[image]

Hopefully someone can help me.

**BREAKTHROUGH**:

[image]

Apparently 3 label instances are made. 0 is the left one, 1 is the right one, and 2 is also the left one but they overlap each other.
All I need to know now is how to delete 2 of those instances.
The code is used to look at the objects. 
I can change it here but setting label[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCTzZ.png) to null and pop(), both do not work.

```
     onRegionTipShow: function (event, label, code) {
      console.log(label)
    },
});
```

Comment: do You create more than one instance of jvectormap?

Comment: no, just one instance. but for some reason the map i load in also has a label.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
   onRegionTipShow: function (event, label, code) {
      console.log(label)
      label.splice(1,1);
      label.splice(2,1);
    },
});
```

[image]

if anyone ever has this issue.
with splice you can delete objects like these.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the jVectorMap source code, the `tip` is created inside the map constructor:

```
jvm.Map = function(params) {
   ...
   this.createTip();
   ...
}
```

I believe the map is for some reasons created more than once, but this is just guessing, because You mentioned the angular component.

You can either:

- Add the `remove` method to Your component and invoke the map `remove` method:

  ```
  $("#worldMap").vectorMap('get','mapObject').remove();
  ```

  ...because this will remove also the `tip`:

  ```
  /**
    * Gracefully remove the map and and all its accessories, unbind event handlers.
  */
  remove: function(){
    this.tip.remove();
    this.container.remove();
    jvm.$('body').unbind('mouseup', this.onContainerMouseUp);
  }
  ```

  Moreover, I would use something like this to clean-up the map:

  ```
  function removeMap() {
    var mapObj = $("#worldMap").vectorMap('get','mapObject');
    if (typeof mapObj.remove !== 'undefined')  {
      mapObj.remove();
      $("#worldMap").contents().remove();
    }
  }
  ```
- You can patch the jVectorMap source code to append the `tip` to the map container, not the `body` (also if You are using more than one map in Your page).

  Replace this line inside jVectorMap:

  ```
  //this.tip = jvm.$('<div/>').addClass('jvectormap-tip').appendTo(jvm.$('body'));
  this.tip = jvm.$('<div/>').addClass('jvectormap-tip').appendTo(this.container);
  ```

Comment: thanks for commenting i just solved the issue look above. i have no idea if yours does the same. but the problem is that i do not use any of this code. i do not generate the tips myself. the npm package does that for me. and i wanted just once to stay left and it looks like your code removes it all.

Comment: No worries, I never thought You are generating the tips by yourself. I edited my answer to be more clear. Please, pay attention that also the `mouseup` event is bound to the `body`. Maybe try to check it out.